# Weird behaviour for transactions in django 1.6.1

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, transactions

I am using transaction.atomic as a context manager for transactions in django 1.6. There is a block of code which I want to be in a transaction which has a couple of network calls and some database writes. I am seeing very weird behaviour. Every once in while (maybe 1 in 20 times) I have noticed a partial rollback happening without any exception having been raised and the view executing without any errors. My application is hosted on heroku and we use heroku postgres v9.2.8. Pseudo code:

```
from django.db import transaction

def some_view(request):

    try:
        with transation.atomic():
            network_call_1()
            db_write_1.save(update_fields=['col4',])
            db_write_2.save(update_fields=['col3',])
            db_write_3.save(update_fields=['col1',])
            network_call_2()
            db_write_4.save(update_fields=['col6',])
            db_write_5.bulk_create([object1, object2])
            db_write_6.bulk_create([object1, object2])
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error(e)

    return HttpResponse()
```

The behaviour that I have noticed is that without any exception having been raised, either db write 1-3 have rolled back and the rest gone through or db write 1 has been rolled back and rest have gone through and so on. I don't understand why this should be happening. First, if there is a rollback, shouldn't it be a complete rollback of the transaction? If there is a rollback shouldn't an exception also be raised so that I know a rollback has happened? Everytime this has happened, no exception has been raised and the code just continues executing and returns a successful HttpResponse.

Relevant settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
CONN_MAX_AGE = None
```

This bug has me baffled since days. Any clues will be of great help!

Comment: I removed my answer as @almalki proved I was wrong in my understanding of the docs. However, I'm thinking that the main problem here is you're not getting an exception, so you don't know what's wrong. To that end, it still seems plausible (to me at least) that your ambiguous `try` block might be swallowing up an inner error. Can you give my suggestion a try at least, and tell me if that mattered or not?

Comment: Also - are you perhaps using `autocommit=False`?

Comment: Django 1.6 by default uses autocommit=True. I haven't set it to False. Unless I'm wrong about the default behaviour, I think I'm good as far as autocommit is concerned. The try is outside the transaction block. Even if the error was being silently eaten up, the entire transaction should've rolled back. Partial rollbacks can't happen unless explicitly performed. That's the main reason I'm baffled by this.

Comment: yes, autocommit is True by default. I was asking because django 1.6.2 introduced a fix for a problem with `autcommit=False`... Well anyway, I can't tell what's the problem, but maybe try adding `autocommit=True` to your database configuration ([here's how](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/databases/#autocommit-mode)) so it will be enforced at the database level. Maybe that'll help

Comment: How reproducible is this?  I'd approach this by setting PostgreSQL log_statements='all' so that I can see exactly what the sequence of commands issued to PostgreSQL is.

Comment: @jjanes Not very reproducible at all. Locally i've seen it like once in over a 100 times, maybe more. On production, it seems to happen more frequently but can't turn logging to all on production.

Comment: I know you said no exceptions are raised, but do you see anything in the postgresql log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of debugging, we have found the culprit.

When we start our application on gunicorn, it spawns workers. Every request coming to the same worker uses the same django DatabaseWrapper instance (postgres in our case) also referred to as a connection. If, in the middle of a transaction in one request, the worker were to receive another request, this request resets the state of the connection causing the transaction to behave in unexpected ways as documented in this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21239
Sometimes the transaction doesn't get committed and there is no exception raised to let you know that happened. Sometimes parts of it do get committed while the rest is lost and it looks like a partial rollback.

We thought that a connection is thread safe, but this bit of gunicorn patching magic here makes sure that's not the case: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/18.0/gunicorn/management/commands/run_gunicorn.py#L16

Still open to suggestions on how to sidestep this issue if possible at all.

EDIT: Don't use the run_gunicorn management command to start Django. It does some funky patching which causes DB connections to not be thread safe. The solution that worked for us is to just use "gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -c gunicorn.conf". Django persistent DB connections don't work with the gevent worker type yet so avoid using that unless you want to run out of connections.

Comment: I still think my answer above is valid. You must add "raise" at the end of except.

Comment: @matija Your answer makes sense if catching an exception inside a transaction block. Even then, it's perfectly ok to catch a non db exception if you want. Any DB exception within the transaction block will kill the transaction. There won't be any partial commits/rollbacks in that case though.

Comment: I checked the code of "atomic". It seems that only DatabaseError does the rollback. So my answer is not valid, but it still may be the cause for your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Django expert, but I do know Postgres. I agree with your assessment that this sounds like very atypical behavior for a transaction: the rollback should be all-or-nothing, and there should be an exception. That being the case, can you be absolutely certain that this is a rollback-type situation? There are lots of other possible causes that could account for different data appearing in the database than you expected, and many of those scenarios would fit better with your observed occurrences that does a rollback.

You haven't provided any specifics as to your data, but what I imagine is, you're seeing something like "I set the value of col4 to 'foo', but after the commit, the old value 'bar' is still in the database." Is that correct?

If so, then other possible causes could be:

- The code that is supposed to setting the 'foo' value somehow, on occasion, is actually setting either the existing 'bar' value, or a NULL value.
- The code is setting the 'foo' value, but the there is a data access layer (aka DAL) with a 'dirty' flag that is not being set (e.g. if the object is in a disconnected state), so when the commit is done, the DAL doesn't see that as being a change it is supposed to write.

These are just a few examples to get you started. There are lots of other possible scenarios. Sometimes, the basic philosophy of debugging problems like this is similar to the problem of the DDT and pelicans: since the database is at the top of the food chain, you can often see problems there that-- while they appear to be database problems-- are actually caused somewhere else in your solution.

Good luck and hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have considered those options as well and they are indeed possible. I should probably update my code example with this but I haven't included that there is also a db read that happens there. So what i do is a.col1 = 'foo'; a.save(update_fields=['col1']) and then i also do b = A.objects.get(id=a.id) and then log b.col1 and it's 'foo'. So we do know that write reached the db cache.

Comment: Got it; very helpful. Some additional tests/thoughts: (1) Do you ever see the same behavior (I'll call it "failure to commit" rather than "rollback") if you commit each statement separately rather than all together? (2) In your "b = A.objects.get(id=a.id)" test above, what do you see if you do the same test immediately after the commit? Is there any difference if you do it on the same DB connection vs. opening a new, separate DB connection?

Answer (score 1):

My 3 cents:

#### Exceptions

We're certain no exceptions have occurred. But are we? Your pseudo-code "handles" an exception by just logging. Make sure there are no exceptions "handled" elsewhere by `logging` or `pass`.

#### The partial rollback

We expect the the whole transaction to be rolled back, not just part. Since django 1.6 *nested* atomic transactions create a [savepoint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints) and rollbacks go back to the last savepoint. Make sure there are no nested transactions. Perhaps you have [transaction middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#transaction-middleware) active check [ATOMIC_REQUESTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) and [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES). Maybe transactions are started in those `network_call` functions.

#### Reproducing

Since that `network_call` code may block. Try to replace them with mock calls, that timeout (maybe not in production). If that results in 100% (partial) rollbacks. It should make locating the problem of partial rollbacks easier.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just make few remarks first.

It is not necessary to have an exception in this code and still have rollback.

Maybe there is some kind of timeout outside this code. Think if you killed python process in the middle of the second network call. This particular exception would not be logged.

I would also recommend adding

`raise`

at the end of except, it will log and re-raise the same exception. Cacthing all exceptions is rarely good.

Also, there might be a threading issue. Try importing threding and logging current thread id in your logger with the exception. You may find out that you actually have more than one thread, so one has to wait on another.

Generally, it is not a good idea to have some external calls in the middle of transaction.

Do both your calls before you start atomic transaction, so it can be as fast as possible.

Hope this helps.